# C#'s version of JS's JSON

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently got into C# using Unity. I previously worked with JavaScript and know that they defiantly have their differences, but still have some similarities. I have used JSON with JS and it works great. Now with Unity, I want to store data of upcoming "stages" in JSON in an infinite runner game. But from my experience, JSON does not work nearly as well with C# as it does with JS. I have looked at Unity's [JSON Utility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) but haven't figured out if it's possible to simply have a string and then convert it into an object which you could access like `object.item.array[0].item` which is how you'd do it in JS. Another thing that I looked at was [this](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp) but as a novice to C#, I couldn't make heads or tails of it. So does C# have something like JSON, but its more integrated? I've used C# lists, can you get 3D lists with items and not just arrays? I know that they are very different languages, and what works well on one, might not on another.

Comment: The standard for json in C# is (in my opinion so not adding as an answer) Newtonsoft.Json just install the nuget package. Beyond that you'd be better off asking a specific question about a specific problem. Generic "how do lists work in C#" type questions are a bit vague to get good answers.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. C# is much more strongly typed than JavaScript, so "traditional" JSON techniques won't work very well. Of course you can get C# objects to and from JSON with either library mentioned. What did you want to know?

Comment: @Ben Thanks, that seems much similar than everything I've seen to far. I think that's what I'll end up using.

Comment: @Ruzihm, I saw that just was seeing if there was a way to simply convert a string to JSON object via C#. From what I saw, it seems to be doing the opposite in ~10 different ways.

Comment: @JackStoller Anywhere that says "Deserialize" on that page is talking about going from JSON->C# object. What you mean when you say "string to JSON object" is vague. The part where it says "Deserialize json string without class" might address that.

Comment: @Ruzihm Sorry for being vague, but from what I understand they start out with a C# Class, then go to a JSON string, then using both the string and the C# Class, create a C# Object. I was wondering if you could skip the C# class and start out with just a JSON string and go to a C# Object. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @JackStoller definitely take a look at the "Deserialize json string without class" then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think closest to what you describe in your questions and the comments as

> simply convert a JSON string into a JSONObject

would maybe be the good old [`SimpleJSON`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON). Simply copy the [`SimpleJSON.cs`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON#SimpleJSON.cs) and depending on your needs maybe [`SimpleJSONUnity.cs`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON#SimpleJSONUnity.cs_.28Extension_file.29)(provides some extensions for directly parsing to and from `Vector2`, `Vector3`, `Vector4`, `Quaternion`, `Rect`, `RectOffset` and `Matrix4x4`) somewhere into your `Assets` folder.

Then given the example json

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "data": {
        "sampleArray": [
            "string value",
            5,
            {
                "name": "sub object"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

you can simply access single fields like

```
using SimpleJSON;

...

var jsonObject = JSON.Parse(the_JSON_string);

string versionString = jsonObject["version"].Value;         // versionString will be a string containing "1.0"
float versionNumber = jsonObject["version"].AsFloat;        // versionNumber will be a float containing 1.0
string val = jsonObject["data"]["sampleArray"][0];          // val contains "string value"
string name = jsonObject["data"]["sampleArray"][2]["name"]; // name will be a string containing "sub object"
...
```

Using this you don't have to re-create the entire c# class representation of the JSON data which might sometimes be a huge overhead if you just want to access a single value from the JSON string.

---

However if you want to serialze and deserialize entire data structures you won't get happy using `SimpleJSON`. Given the example above this is how you would use Unity's [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html)

Create the c# class representation of the data yu want to store. In this case e.g. something like

```
[Serializable]
public class RootObject
{
    public string version = "";
    public Data data = new Data();
}

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public List<object> sampleArray = new List<object>();
}

[Serializeable]
public class SubData
{
    public string name = "";
}
```

Then fill it with values and parse it to JSON like

```
var jsonObject = new RootObject()
    {
        version = "1.0",
        data = new Data()
            {
                sampleArray = new List<object>()
                    {
                        "string value",
                        5,
                        new SubData(){ name = "sub object" }
                    }
            }
    };

var jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(jsonObject);
```

And to convert it back to c# either if `jsonObject` was not created yet

```
jsonObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

otherwise

```
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(jsonString, jsonObject);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just how objects are represented in JavaScript. While C# can use JSON, you'll probably have a much easier time defining your own custom [classes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-class-and-object/). Using classes, you can define all the properties you'll need, string them together into a list, etc.. Hope this helps.